# How to save a new line in input stream? Java - Android

Tags: java, android, inputstream, outputstream

I want to save text with InputStream from EditText while preserving new lines in the text.

Here's the example of what I'm trying to do:

```
    public void onSaveButtonClick(View v) {
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter out= new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("STORETEXTBELESKE.txt", 0));

        out.write(beleskeEditText.getText().toString());

        out.close();
    }

    catch (Throwable t) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Exception: " + t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

And here is the part of reading the text from the saved file:

```
    public void readSavedFile() {
    try {
        InputStream in = openFileInput("STORETEXTBELESKE.txt");

        if (in != null) {

            InputStreamReader tmp = new InputStreamReader(in);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(tmp);
            String str;
            StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();

            while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                buf.append(str);

            }
            in.close();
            beleskeEditText.setText(buf.toString());
        }
    } catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Exception: " + t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

And it partially works. All the text is saved correctly but everything is in the same line.

So if the input is:

Test
test
123

Output is: Testtest123

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do this

```
while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      buf.append(str);
      buf.append('\n');
}
```

Comment: Of course, that's the answer. It's working now as intended. Thanks!

Comment: @qwerasdzxc Glad to hear it!  Good luck.